# How to use CSS on autocomplete textbox selected values

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Every time the client select an item from the autocomplete textbox, it automaticly appears in a div I created right under the textbox.
I would like to style with css **each** selected item that appears in the div, and not the whole div. For example, I want that every selected item will appear with a black border. (I could easily use css on the div, but then i'll get border for the whole div and not on each item selected).

That's the JS code. What i need is to add CSS to any new Selected country.

```
$(function() {
     /* Textbox ID */ $("#destinations").autocomplete({
        select: function (event, ui) {
           /* div ID */ $("#DestinationsChosen").html(function(i, origText)
            {
                var SelectedCountry = ui.item.value.toString();
                var CurrentText = origText.toString();
                if ((CurrentText.indexOf(SelectedCountry) >= 0))
                {
                    alert("Already Exists");
                    return CurrentText;
                }
                return CurrentText + " " + SelectedCountry;
            })
        }
    });
})
```

Here is the whole code: http://jsfiddle.net/3zfcb04k/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
return CurrentText + " " + SelectedCountry;
```

to this:

```
return CurrentText + " <span>" + SelectedCountry + "</span><br/>";
```

Then apply the CSS on the `span` tag.

[Here is the updated **JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3zfcb04k/1/)

Answer (score 0):

try to put the css on the class="ui-menu-item"

```
.ui-menu-item{
  color:red;
}
```

[image]